# Why won't my submit from Knockout bind to my MVC Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a knockout model that is feeding my page and on a save the following code is executed client side.

```
self.save = function() {
    var tirerun = ko.mapping.toJSON(self.data());
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "@Url.Action("SaveTireRunModel", "Events")",
        data: tirerun,
        success: function(result) {
            if (!result.success) {
                alert(result.error);
            } else {}
        }
    });
};
```

It then posts the following JSON to my server (From fiddler and cropped for brevity)
[image]

With the following http request header

```
POST http://localhost:63648/Events/SaveTireRunModel HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:63648
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1975
Origin: http://localhost:63648
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko)         Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:63648/Events/OutingDetails?outingID=010fd8a1-e3a5-e111-a660-f0def1589f4b
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: jstree_open=%232012%2C%23c914324c-4d9f-e111-a79b-0024e8a037d3%2C%23eb-e957-e111-9e70-d067e53b2ed6%2C%234d-c00e-e111-ad1c-0e6e17349d3e%2C%2357-c00e-e111-ad1c-0e6e17349d3e%2C%234d-c00e-e111-ad1c-0e6e17349d3e; jstree_load=; .ASPXAUTH=054DD21DC0A17DDDAAFC254500ED8D6B3299EAABF1FB647732618E956EF082880BBA0B52A59849D3362AA03EB1F27D28867B07CD8451E4E983D84365608AA145F8DF8D71C2481639E110EC31325EE27EA3281FA2EDB7AD31A744D2A9918BE6599DB97E489ED4598D2DF63C31E36E809A282CF96FFCE5ACAEF8308FEA3DF1C6DE50B2AA7299F9D9AF0C30CE867DCCA352; jstree_open=%232012%2C%233dcc4b9b-37a3-e111-a6d3-0026b99ca1da%2C%23eb-e957-e111-9e70-d067e53b2ed6%2C%2357-c00e-e111-ad1c-0e6e17349d3e%2C%23a2962e1b-45a5-e111-b9ac-f0def1589f4b; jstree_load=%2311a4611a-8851-e111-95c7-60d819fcced5%2C%23b89422a0-0d03-e011-99cb-d601d71f0fcf; jstree_select=%23010fd8a1-e3a5-e111-a660-f0def1589f4b

{"Comments":"RSTA Dwn 2 Holes (6)\r\nRF Spring to 35468\r\nCross Dwn to 47.9 (-0.2)","TireSetsList":[{"ID":"1","Value":"1"},{"ID":"2","Value":"2"},{"ID":"3","Value":"3"},{"ID":"4","Value":"4"},{"ID":"5","Value":"5"}],"LFShoulderTemp":245,"RFShoulderTemp":245,"LFOuterTemp":177,"LFMiddleTemp":null,"LFInnerTemp":200,"RFOuterTemp":177,"RFMiddleTemp":null,"RFInnerTemp":200,"LROuterTemp":177,"LRMiddleTemp":null,"LRInnerTemp":200,"RROuterTemp":177,"RRMiddleTemp":null,"RRInnerTemp":200,"LFInitialOuterWear":null,"LFInitialOuterMiddleWear":null,"LFInitialMiddleWear":null,"LFInitialInnerMiddleWear":null,"LFInitialInnerWear":null,"LFAfterOuterWear":null,"LFAfterOuterMiddleWear":null,"LFAfterMiddleWear":200,"LFAfterInnerMiddleWear":null,"LFAfterInnerWear":null,"RFInitialOuterWear":null,"RFInitialOuterMiddleWear":null,"RFInitialMiddleWear":null,"RFInitialInnerMiddleWear":null,"RFInitialInnerWear":null,"RFAfterOuterWear":null,"RFAfterOuterMiddleWear":null,"RFAfterMiddleWear":200,"RFAfterInnerMiddleWear":null,"RFAfterInnerWear":null,"LRInitialOuterWear":null,"LRInitialOuterMiddleWear":null,"LRInitialMiddleWear":null,"LRInitialInnerMiddleWear":null,"LRInitialInnerWear":null,"LRAfterOuterWear":null,"LRAfterOuterMiddleWear":null,"LRAfterMiddleWear":200,"LRAfterInnerMiddleWear":null,"LRAfterInnerWear":null,"RRInitialOuterWear":null,"RRInitialOuterMiddleWear":null,"RRInitialMiddleWear":null,"RRInitialInnerMiddleWear":null,"RRInitialInnerWear":null,"RRAfterOuterWear":null,"RRAfterOuterMiddleWear":null,"RRAfterMiddleWear":200,"RRAfterInnerMiddleWear":null,"RRAfterInnerWear":null,"LFInnerColdPressure":71,"LFInnerHotPressure":null,"RFInnerColdPressure":71,"RFInnerHotPressure":null,"LRInnerColdPressure":71,"LRInnerHotPressure":null,"RRInnerColdPressure":71,"RRInnerHotPressure":null,"LFColdPressure":61.5,"LFHotPressure":69.8,"RFColdPressure":61.5,"RFHotPressure":69.8,"LRColdPressure":61.5,"LRHotPressure":69.8,"RRColdPressure":61.5,"RRHotPressure":69.8,"TrackTemp":133}
```

But when it goes into my action the model is completely null.

```
public JsonResult SaveTireRunModel(TireRunViewModel tirerun)
{
    tirerun.Save();
    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

My model class is as follows

```
public class TireRunViewModel
{

    public TireRunViewModel()
    {

    }

    public TireRunViewModel(Guid outingID)
    {
        //data access crud here
    }

    public string Comments { get; set; }

    public List<SelectBoxModel> TireSetsList { get; set; }

    public double? LFShoulderTemp { get; set; }

    public double? RFShoulderTemp { get; set; }

    public double? LFOuterTemp { get; set; }

    public double? LFMiddleTemp { get; set; }

    public double? LFInnerTemp { get; set; }

    public double? RFOuterTemp { get; set; }

    public double? RFMiddleTemp { get; set; }

    public double? RFInnerTemp { get; set; }

    public double? LROuterTemp { get; set; }

    public double? LRMiddleTemp { get; set; }

    public double? LRInnerTemp { get; set; }

    public double? RROuterTemp { get; set; }

    public double? RRMiddleTemp { get; set; }

    public double? RRInnerTemp { get; set; }

    public double? LFInitialOuterWear { get; set; }

    public double? LFInitialOuterMiddleWear { get; set; }

    public double? LFInitialMiddleWear { get; set; }

    public double? LFInitialInnerMiddleWear { get; set; }

    public double? LFInitialInnerWear { get; set; }

    public double? LFAfterOuterWear { get; set; }

    public double? LFAfterOuterMiddleWear { get; set; }

    public double? LFAfterMiddleWear { get; set; }

    public double? LFAfterInnerMiddleWear { get; set; }

    public double? LFAfterInnerWear { get; set; }

    public double? RFInitialOuterWear { get; set; }

    public double? RFInitialOuterMiddleWear { get; set; }

    public double? RFInitialMiddleWear { get; set; }

    public double? RFInitialInnerMiddleWear { get; set; }

    public double? RFInitialInnerWear { get; set; }

    public double? RFAfterOuterWear { get; set; }

    public double? RFAfterOuterMiddleWear { get; set; }

    public double? RFAfterMiddleWear { get; set; }

    public double? RFAfterInnerMiddleWear { get; set; }

    public double? RFAfterInnerWear { get; set; }

    public double? LRInitialOuterWear { get; set; }

    public double? LRInitialOuterMiddleWear { get; set; }

    public double? LRInitialMiddleWear { get; set; }

    public double? LRInitialInnerMiddleWear { get; set; }

    public double? LRInitialInnerWear { get; set; }

    public double? LRAfterOuterWear { get; set; }

    public double? LRAfterOuterMiddleWear { get; set; }

    public double? LRAfterMiddleWear { get; set; }

    public double? LRAfterInnerMiddleWear { get; set; }

    public double? LRAfterInnerWear { get; set; }

    public double? RRInitialOuterWear { get; set; }

    public double? RRInitialOuterMiddleWear { get; set; }

    public double? RRInitialMiddleWear { get; set; }

    public double? RRInitialInnerMiddleWear { get; set; }

    public double? RRInitialInnerWear { get; set; }

    public double? RRAfterOuterWear { get; set; }

    public double? RRAfterOuterMiddleWear { get; set; }

    public double? RRAfterMiddleWear { get; set; }

    public double? RRAfterInnerMiddleWear { get; set; }

    public double? RRAfterInnerWear { get; set; }

    public double? LFInnerColdPressure { get; set; }

    public double? LFInnerHotPressure { get; set; }

    public double? RFInnerColdPressure { get; set; }

    public double? RFInnerHotPressure { get; set; }

    public double? LRInnerColdPressure { get; set; }

    public double? LRInnerHotPressure { get; set; }

    public double? RRInnerColdPressure { get; set; }

    public double? RRInnerHotPressure { get; set; }

    public double? LFColdPressure { get; set; }

    public double? LFHotPressure { get; set; }

    public double? RFColdPressure { get; set; }

    public double? RFHotPressure { get; set; }

    public double? LRColdPressure { get; set; }

    public double? LRHotPressure { get; set; }

    public double? RRColdPressure { get; set; }

    public double? RRHotPressure { get; set; }

    public int? SetNumberLF { get; set; }

    public int? SetNumberRF  { get; set; }

    public int? SetNumberLR { get; set; }

    public int? SetNumberRR { get; set; }

    public double? TrackTemp { get; set; }

    public void Save()
    {
       //data access crud here
    }
}
```

What can I do to further troubleshoot this and figure out why my model isn't binding?

Comment: Can you post the HTTP request (obtained with fiddler/other) so we can see what data you are actually posting, and also show the definition of `TireRunViewModel`?

Comment: Not a problem...I was just trying to keep it short.  There is a lot of parameters being passed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default contentType for the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

If you want to send JSON you have to specify that your are sending JSON otherwise the Model Binder won't work correctly:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "@Url.Action("SaveTireRunModel", "Events")",
        data: tirerun,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(result) {
            if (!result.success) {
                alert(result.error);
            } else {}
        }
    });
```

You maybe also need to "stringify" the data with : `data: JSON.stringify(tirerun)`

Comment: No need to stringify it, the contenttype is all that it needed.  Thanks.

Comment: Yep, or if you want to send it normally do `var tirerun = ko.mapping.toJS(self.data());` without specific `contentType`.

Answer (score 1):

I had pretty much the same problem - solved it by using `ko.mapping.toJS(myVm)` instead of `ko.mapping.toJSON(myVm)`. When using toJSON, all the vm's properties are sent in a single string concatenated, but using toJS instead, each property is received separately in my controller, thus correctly mapping to my C# Viewmodel, in your case the `TireRunViewModel` class.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you need to specify the `dataType` as well as the `contentType` as for example:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/person/create",
   dataType: "json",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   data: jsonData,
   success: function (result){
       ...
   },
   error: function (error){
       ...
   }
});
```

That should work just fine.(I've highlighted it [here](http://juristr.com/blog/2011/08/posting-json-data-to-aspnet-mvc-3-web/) if you're further interested).

Comment: It is working with just the contentType defined.  What is the purpose of the dataType variable in this case?

Comment: @PlTaylor That would be the kind of data you're expecting back from the server. Normally when you're sending json you'll probably also get some kind of JSON result back (but it doesn't necessarily have to).

Comment: You are correct that I am receiving JSON back.  That always worked without having to set the dataType.  Honestly it is probably just lucky that it works now without it being set.